# Is it possible to archive Facebook Pages?

Tags: facebook-pages

I have a couple of Facebook Pages that are related to projects that no longer exist. I would like to archive these pages without deleting them.

Does Facebook offer such a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Facebook provide any such feature except that [download a copy of data](https://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467/). But you can hide your page from public by unpublishing it.

Unpublished Pages are only visible to the people who manage the Page.

From the [Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/184605634921611):

> Unpublishing your Page will hide it from the public, including the people who like your Page.
>
> To unpublish your Page:
>
> 1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page
> 2. From **General**, click **Page Visibility**
> 3. Click to check the box next to **Unpublish Page**
> 4. Click **Save Changes**
>
> Your Page won't be visible to the public until you publish it again.
>
> Note: You'll need to be an [admin](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410) to unpublish your Page.